# how to use the kdl parser

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear Sir,

I have been trying to use the KDL parser in ros to find the kinematic model of the robot arm urdf description in .xml

Could you please guide me how to use the KDL parser as it is not clear through the kdl_parser documentation.

Thanking you for your time

Regards
rdd0101

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57930/how-to-use-the-kdl-parser/) by [rdd0101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4404/rdd0101/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-03-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I thought the kdl_parser [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/kdl_parser/Tutorials/Start%20using%20the%20KDL%20parser) gave a fairly clear usage explanation:

```
#include <kdl_parser/kdl_parser.hpp>
KDL::Tree robot_kin;
kdl_parser::treeFromFile("my_robot.urdf", robot_kin);
```

(the tutorial also provides similar examples for initializing from a parameter or string)

Once you have a KDL::Tree, you probably want to calculate various sorts of kinematics.  The KDL Documentation provides some good examples [here](http://www.orocos.org/kdl/examples):

```
KDL::Chain chain;
robot_kin.getChain("base_link", "tool", chain);

KDL::JntArray joint_pos(chain.getNrOfJoints());
KDL::Frame cart_pos;
KDL::ChainFkSolverPos_recursive fk_solver(chain);
fk_solver.JntToCart(joint_pos, cart_pos);
```

---

However, you might consider staying within the ROS framework for basic kinematics, rather than working in KDL directly.  This allows you to use ROS functions to extract different kinematic groups, use robot-specific kinematics plugins, detect collisions, etc.

The approach differs between whether you are using [arm_navigation](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_kinematics/Tutorials) or [moveIt](http://moveit.ros.org/wiki/index.php/Groovy/Kinematics/C%2B%2B_API).  Both are fairly well documented, with examples at the links given above.

---

Originally posted by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) with karma: 4976 on 2013-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2